# 18.04 Can't set default sound output

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, default

I have an Intel NUC7i3 that works as a HTPC and smart home controller.

It has two sound output devices: internal PCI sound card which outputs through HDMI and generic USB sound card attached to a small speaker used by Domoticz to output voice alerts when TV is off.

I'm experiencing two weird issues with this setup, maybe they are connected to each other:

1. When TV is on and HDMI is set as default output (Domoticz usues mpd which is set to use only the USB card) most sounds play through HDMI as they should, but some (eg. warning before closing FF with multiple tabs) play through USB card.
2. After every reboot USB card is set as default output. I followed this instruction:  [LINK](https://rastating.github.io/setting-default-audio-device-in-ubuntu-18-04/).
   However - when I enter `pactl list short sinks` right after a reboot I get a list like

   ```
   0 USB device
   1 PCI device
   ```

   USB is default. When I try

   ```
   pactl set-default-sink 'PCI device'
   ```

   I get an error:

   ```
   Error: no such device
   ```

   And now when I go to Settings->Sound and select HDMI as default manually

   ```
   pactl list short sinks
   ```

   output changes to

   ```
   0 USB device
   2 PCI device
   ```

Only after this can I use

```
pactl set-default-sink
```

to change outputs. Because of this adding `set-default-sink` to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` does not work - the PCI device gives "No such device" error when the script is processed. I also cannot use startup or post startup scripts because PCI device gives this error until it's manually selected in settings.

Does anyone have any idea on how to approach this issue?

Comment: One thing to try, it helped me in similar situation, 'pavucontrol -t 5'. After I installed it and checked all the boxes in advanced my output managed to survive reboot.